# How to create one navigation with multiple commands

Tags: php, javascript, css

I am trying to build a navigation that determines the page the user in on and gives that link a different command to show a div tag if you click it on the current page. Example: you click on the home page to go to the home page. if you are on the home page and you click home again it causes a div tag to fade in. I have the div tag working but I don't know how to apply more than one command to an  tag. I want the navigation to just be a sitewide include incase I have to make further updates to the site. Right now I have individual navigation on each page.

Comment: simply put a jquery hide div function on the onclick @ the same page (try a logic)
@ Home Page -> (PUT CODE TO HIDE HOME DIV)

Answer (score 2):

In PHP you can learn about the page that has been requested by using the value in [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and related entries.

You can then take it to decide on which page you are and change the display of the menu according to the requested page.

This allows you to include the menu template from many different files regardless where inside your page structure these are located.

A short example, here with your suggested `PHP_SELF` entry and a non-directory structure:

```
<?php

    $currentPage = basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);

    /** define the menu **/
    $menu = array(
        array('index.php', 'home');
    );

    /** process the menu **/    
    foreach ($menu as &$entry) {
        list($page, $name) = $entry;
        $isCurrent = $currentPage === $page;
        if ($isCurrent) {                
            $href  = '#';
            $extra = ' onclick="MM_effectAppearFade(display, 2500, 0, 100, true)"';
        } else {
            $href  = $page;
            $extra = '';
        }
        $entry = array_merge($entry, array($href, $extra));
    }
    unset($entry);

    /** output the menu **/
?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach($menu as $entry) { ?>
        <li>
            <?php
                list($page, $name, $href, $extra) = $entry;
                printf(
                    '<a href="%s"%s>%s</a></li>', 
                    $href, $extra, htmlspecialchars($name)
                );
             ?>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: ok I am completely new to this so here is my navigation code. maybe you can tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: $currentFile = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
$parts = Explode('/', $currentFile);
echo $parts[count($parts) - 1];

Comment: if ($currentFile =="index.php")
  {
 <li><a href="#" onclick="MM_effectAppearFade(display, 2500, 0, 100, true)">home</a></li>
  }
  else
  {
     <li><a href="index.php">home</a></li>
  }

Comment: replace `;` with `,` - I just quickly typed it and didn't run it, so bear with some minor problems.

Comment: @ hakre  I am getting an error on this part of the code   $menu = array(
        array('index.php', 'home');
  array('wicked_team.php', 'the wicked team');
  array('our_distillery.php', 'our distillery');
  array('artisian_rum.php', 'artisian rum');
  array('wicked_events.php', 'wicked events');
  array('wicked_news.php', 'wicked news');
  array('contact.php', 'contact us'))
    );

Comment: Inside the menu array, sub-arrays need to be separated by `,` not `;`, I made the error while typing this.

Comment: This worked great @hekre. I had to tweak the code a little but it is working fantastic. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> apply more than one command to an tag

I assume you are using `onlick` attributes in the element. Don't do that. Assign any event handler from a separate script. You can bind as much events to an element as you want (and also as much callbacks to an event as you want).

jQuery example:

```
jQuery( '#menu a' ).on( 'click', function( event ) {
    if( event.target.attr( 'href' ) == window.location ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery( '#specialDivPopup' ).show();
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

simply put a jquery hide div function on the onclick @ the same page (try a logic)

@ Home Page -> (PUT CODE TO HIDE HOME DIV ON CLICK)

@ MYPAGE Page -> (PUT CODE TO HIDE MYPAGE DIV ON CLICK)